# When i read the list of files in a diectory i get two files "." and "..", why?

Tags: c, file

Hello guys im writing a program c that have to read a list of files in a directory, but when I print the names of files there are 2 file: "." and "..".
Is there any way to prevent it from reading these two files, without doing an explicit check?

My code is:

```
d = opendir("myfolder");
if (d) {
    while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL){  
        strcpy(path,"myfolder");
        strcat(path,"/");
        strcat(path,dir->d_name);
        printf("File name: %s ",dir->d_name);
    }
    //... other things like closing dir and file.
```

Comment: Every directory has those two special directories ("current directory" and "parent directory"). Just check for them and skip them if you don't need to refer to them.

Comment: It's the standard *current directory* (for `.`) and *parent directory* (for `..`).

Comment: (Also, that `strcpy()` and multiple inefficient `strcat()`'s can be replaced with a single `snprintf()`)

Comment: @Shawn how I should do this? I mean how i should us snprintf in this case? sorry im new in C

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf has documentation for `snprintf()`

Comment: @Shawn, Re "*Every directory has those two special directories*", Almost every. The root of drives usually don't have those in Windows. (I say usually, because a none-root dir mapped to a drive using `subst` does, for example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because files with those names exist in the directory.

```
$ ls -1a
.
..
.bash_history
.bash_logout
.bashrc
  ⋮
bin
projects
tmp
usr
```

- `.` is a hardlink to the directory that contains it.
- `..` is a hardlink to the parent of the directory that contains it.

Most of the time, you want to ignore files that have a name starting with "`.`".

Similar idea in Windows.